# Idiomatic Python: Case insensitivity

Tags: python, case-sensitive, idioms

I am finding that the hardest thing about Python is getting into the Pythonic 'mindset'. It is different getting used to users being thought of as competent adults because for so long I've been trained that you protect your code from misuse.

Using the following as an example:

```
TEMPS = {
    'Low': 300,
    'Medium': 350,
    'High': 425,
    'Broil': 500
}

def check_temp(temp_input):
    """User must match key in TEMPS exactly"""
    if temp_input in TEMPS:
        print(TEMPS.get(temp_input))

def ci_check_temp(temp_input):
    """User must only match case-insensitively"""
    if temp_input.upper() in (temp.upper() for temp in TEMPS.keys()):
        print(TEMPS.get(temp_input.capitalize()))

>>>check_temp('Low')
300
>>>ci_check_temp('Low')
300
>>>check_temp('LoW')
>>>ci_check_temp('LoW')
300
>>>check_temp('MediuM')
>>>ci_check_temp('MediuM')
350
```

So should we assume users (whether that means programmers or end-users) are competent adults and force exact matches in cases like these or should we guide them and make small assumptions, like that they probably meant 'Low' when they typed 'LOw' in the above example? Or is this dictated by each case? In most cases should I make options case-insensitive like this or let the user make mistakes with my python libraries and possibly deal with the consequences?

I don't want to assume users are *trying* to break my code and are vicious, but I don't want to assume they won't ever make honest mistakes either. Where is the pythonic middle ground?

Comment: Assume that users are trying to break your code. The traditional way is to compare the lowercase (or uppercase) of the users' inputs to pre-cased strings (or similar). In this case, make your keys lowercase.

Comment: why don't you make your keys lowercase and lower every string before trying the dict?

Comment: I think the idea of "consenting adults" in Python has more to do with programmers than users, (for example, no private class members). It should be assumed that users will make reasonable mistakes

Comment: When lowering (or upper-ing) the input from the user, is it permissible to redefine the parameter or should a new variable be made? For example, would python coders cringe at:

def my_function(input_str):
    input_str = input_str.lower()
    # do something with input_str

Comment: Well my personal experience when I first saw Python was indeed: hmm, people will now and then do things in the not intended way. But Python allows you to be very declarative: usually you do not alter a list, you construct a new one where you filter out the values you do not need, etc. If you use Python the wrong way, it will definitely introduce errors, but from the moment you alter datastructures too much, you should start thinking: "hmm... there has to be a more elegant way."

Comment: The notion of "consenting adults" applies to programmers interacting with other programmer's code; not users.  When a user interacts with your program, you still need to build in certain safeguards to ensure the interaction occurs the way you expect.  I typically refer to this as "making users successful, in-spite of themselves."  To fix your issue, you should uppercase, or lowercase your input strings and compare them to the same case keys in your dict.